# Proper way of using "furthermore"

Tags: word-request, word-order

I am confused about the word **furthermore** in the middle of the sentence.
Can I use it like this?

> However currently both systems are functioning, furthermore, for
>   different issues.

It is put in the middle of the sentence without any additional verb. Is it right? And does it make sense?

Also are the words **furthermore** and **moreover** interchangeable?

Comment: You are **confused about**, not **confusing**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although **furthermore** can be used as you do in your sentence, it usually introduces a new clause, appearing at the head of the clause. You will find **moreover** far more often in your pattern.

On a separate issue, the phrase **functioning for different issues** while grammatical, is not quite idiomatic.  The usual phrase is **addressing different issues**.

The word **both** is wrong (unless there's a third issue in the context).

> both systems are addressing different issues.

You'd want to say **each**;

> ... each system is addressing a different issue.

And you don't want to combine **However** and **furthermore** in the same clause.

Comment: Then how can I rephrase this sentence so it wouldn't miss any piece of my message? 
"However currently both systems are functioning, moreover, each is addressing a different issue". Does it make sense?

Comment: @Gamilato: I don't know what it is you are trying to say since you begin in the middle of the thought. What came before "However"?

Comment: Ah the context is that the new office system is being implemented, while the previous one is still available, so they both are operational. So they now have different working purposes. And I need to say that super shortly, that is why I put so many in that sentence.

Comment: I am still not clear on what you want to say.  Is it something like this: *Although the new system has been brought online, the old system is still available **for a variety of reasons.***   Is that what you mean to say by "for different reasons"?

Comment: I said "different issues", because there are issues in that systems that employees work on. So it is slightly different. But anyway thank you for your answer, it helped!

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "issues".

Comment: @Gamilato I would suggest an alternative phrasing for your sentence. Something along the lines of: *However, both systems are currently functioning and, furthermore, they are functioning even as they address different issues.*

Comment: That's a little bit too long, isn't it